# Styling Full Hover Effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I want a css hover effect to last on all sections of a particular list item but it seems like there is added margins on the bottom and left and right of the list item that I can't seem to get rid off. I know this is probably a pretty basic css question but I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2497/

I was using bootstrap to get my base css but I don't think that is affecting it.

My Code is:

```
#navbar {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

#nav_container li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#nav_container li:hover {
    background: #333;   
}

#nav_container li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #00;
    padding: 10px;
}

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div id="nav_container"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You had left and right margins on `li` tags. Also, when using `inline-blocks`, be aware they add their own space too. I removed the left and right margins from the `li` and added a negative margin to combat the space added by `inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/TQ3Js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using inline-block on your li tags. What you need to do is apply float:left; and display:block; . Then apply a clearfix to the UL.  Inline-block treats elements similar to how text is handled and includes line-height and spaces.

Comment: `Inline-block` is fine too, just apply a negative margin.

Comment: Actually you just need float:left because floated elements are treated as block level anyways.

Comment: Why don't you look at my fiddle i added to the OPs answer as a comment. Both approaches work (i.e. Floated block level elements OR Inline-block with negative margin offset)

Comment: Both approaches do work, thank you! There is only one thing that seems off, the bottom of the navbar doesn't highlight when I hover but each item on hover is properly highlighted. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @JackWilliams you would still run into bottom margin issues which you could work around by aligning line-heights up.  In my experience floats are a bit more reliable for this kind of thing.  That said using inline-block does allow for a centered nav layout.

Comment: I'd recommend adding display block to the A tags and move the padding and hover to them. More of a click area that way.